# What is the code of autorun.inf?

Tags: 10.04, usb

I have just installed Ubuntu LTS (lucid lynx) 10.04.3 into my USB stick. But when I insert it to a computer in a computer shop, a program named autorun remover automatically removed the file autorun.inf, making Ubuntu LTS unusable. I want to make the file using notepad, but what is the code that I need to type?

Comment: After you recreated it ... make the file read only.

Comment: probably some anti-virus, disable the anti-virus from an M$ pc.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, what about putting your Live image on an SD card, which has a hardware write-protect feature, in order to prevent marauding Windows security software from messing with it.

Comment: Note that the autorun is only for installing via WUBI, which is icky anyhow.  Just boot from the drive instead.

Answer (score 3):

I have this on my 12.04 LTS autorun.inf:

```
[autorun]
open=wubi.exe --cdmenu
icon=wubi.exe,0
label=Install Ubuntu

[Content]
MusicFiles=false
PictureFiles=false
VideoFiles=false
```